# Error message when creating a scatter chart

Tags: r, scatter-plot

I'm trying to make scatter chart, but  error message occurs and can't knit.

```
{r}
ggplot
(railgun,aes(smile, voteshare)) geom_point()
```

Then `[ Error: unexpected ',' in "(railgun,"]` came out.
https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/ggplot2-cheatsheet.pdf
I referred to left side of page, but it won't work.

I know `[,]` is the wrong spot, but how can I replace other things?

Comment: What does "can't knit" mean?

Comment: Shouldn't it be: `ggplot(railgun, aes(smile, voteshare)) + geom_point() `?

Comment: thanks for reply, I appreciate it. "knit" means the way convert html file.

Comment: thecatalyst    I tried it but it won't work...